# Fixing line endings in git

Tags: php, git, github

when i push the files which i modified arent showing the correct difference with the files in the github. What i mean actually is

Am using windows 7 as operating system and the files i pulled from git hub are unix line endings. After i edit the files and push them to repo , on github its hard to find out what changes i made for my collaborator . I tried fixing them manually using "Edit->EOL conversion -> unix "  in notepad++ . For some files it is working and some arent working. I need some one who can help me to make the file line endings to default settings like unix or make them as they are which mean when am downloading they are unix and want them in unix line endings.

I tried dream weaver preferences also but it did not work. help me guys please

*this is my first question over stack overflow if am bad at explanation please ignore . Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this: `git config --global core.autocrlf true`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check your line ending settings in Git.
Read here: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Answer (score 0):

Git provides options to deal with newline issues. Here's a chapter on configuration from Git Book (known also as Pro Git), which is a terrific resource by the way. I recommend reading the whole thing.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace